# Struct inside a Class with another Class as parameter

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a project to work on. 
It has a Class Temp, which has few functions. 
Then there's another Class Weather which stores data in a Struct called Observation. This struct has one it's fields of type class Temp.

```
Class Temp {
Temp();
Temp(string t);
string getTemp();
void setTemp(string temp); 
};

Class Weather
{
```

@beta

in my Weather class 
i have few functions which call class Temp

```
// Weather.h

public:

void record(Temp temp, float d); // error 'Temp' has not been declared
Temp getTemp() const; // 'Temp' does not name a type

 protected: 
 struct Observation 
 {
   Temp t;
   int deg;
 }; 
 Observation obs[20];
};

 // Weather.cpp 

 void Temp::record(Temp temp, float d){
 obs[i].temp = temp; 
 obs[i].deg = d;
 i++;

 }
```

I have tried creating an instance of Temp and Weather. 
But I am not able to get to the Temp t inside the struct.

```
int main(){
Temp t;
Weather w;
w.record(tt,dd); 
}
```

Please guide me...

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
obs[i].tp;
```

makes no sense, because an `Observation` has no field named `tp`. Try this:

```
int record(Temp tp, float d){
 obs[i].t = tp; 
 obs[i].deg = d;
 i++;
}

...

int main(){
Temp t;
Weather w;
int dd=7;
w.record(t,dd); 
}
```

Comment: I have written both the classes in separate header and source files. The Weather.h file is not recognizing Temp.h in it's function declarations... that's one of the errors... how do I fix it?

Comment: @hakuna12: It's difficult to say, since *you haven't shown us the complete code*, but my guess is that you neglect to `#include "Temp.h"` in `Weather.h`.

Comment: I have included Temp.h ... 
I am not sure of posting the entire code here since it's my project. sorry.

Comment: @hakuna12: You don't have to post the *entire* code (and I hope you won't). You can post a [*minimal complete example*](http://www.sscce.org/), which really wouldn't reveal anything sensitive except a mildly embarrassing lacuna in your software development expertise (and preparing such an example is a hugely valuable skill, so it's a good trade). It would also be nice to give us the *exact error message*.

Comment: If you can't bother to quote an error message, or follow a link and find out what "minimal complete example" means, then I feel no impulse to try to solve this problem given only the crumbs of information you've presented.

Comment: I did include the error message with the corresponding code in my answer.

Comment: @hakuna12: Ah, that explains why I missed it. You should add such material by editing your Question, not by posting a non-answer Answer. Anyway, the "little snippet" is not sufficient.

Comment: Oh okay... sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your struct to have access to Temp you need to make Temp public.
Try this:

```
class Temp {
public: 
Temp();
Temp(string t);
string getTemp();
void setTemp(string temp); 
};
```

Now to get Weather accessible in main you need to do the same thing.

```
class Weather{
int i;

public:
// method to used to record all values
int record(Temp tp, float d){
obs[i].t = tp;
obs[i].deg = d;
i++;
}
```

Also, in main you are passing undefined variables to Weather with this line:

```
w.record(tt,dd);
```

Comment: Ok, well the code you posted doesn't have an access specifier and that will prevent your struct from being able to call the constructor of the Temp class.